# When exactly session is created in java web application development?

Tags: java, web-applications

Is session created after deploying the application into the  server or 
after logging into the application?

Answer (score 0):

A user session is/(should be) created after the successful login of the user into the system and it will be valid till the user logs out of the system or the session expires after the session timeout.

Answer (score 0):

When I think in terms of tomcat (for example), when the user logs in, and there is a call for creating a new session, Tomcat creates a sessionID cookie and sends it back to the browser so that this state is preserved in the browser. When the session is invalidated, this cookie is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> Is session created after deploying the application into the server

Of course not. A session is associated with a user. There are no users at deployment time. The question doesn't begin to make sense.

> or after logging into the application?

Yes, or whenever a session is requested after the user's existing session has been invalidated.